# Finding whether a point lies inside a rectangle or not

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I want to find whether a point lies inside a rectangle or not. The rectangle can be oriented in any way, and need not be axis aligned.

One method I could think of was to rotate the rectangle and point coordinates to make the rectangle axis aligned and then by simply testing the coordinates of point whether they lies within that of rectangle's or not.

The above method requires rotation and hence floating point operations. Is there any other efficient way to do this?

Comment: You could do a quick check to see if the point fell in the orthogonal bounding box of the rotated rectangle, and fast fail if not. (Yes, that's only half an answer (hmmm, there are three orthogonal boxes that can be formed by the corner points... and it's late (conceptual geometry is the first to go))).

Comment: But I have to rotate first right?

Comment: Untill you tell us how you rectangle is defined, there won't by much practical value in the answers. When you are working with integer coordinates, the method used to represent the shape has critical importance when selecting the algorithm.

Comment: May be this simple answer is ok https://programming-idioms.org/idiom/178/check-if-point-is-inside-rectangle/4108/csharp ?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

How is the rectangle represented? Three points? Four points? Point, sides and angle? Two points and a side? Something else? Without knowing that, any attempts to answer your question will have only purely academic value.

In any case, for any *convex* polygon (including rectangle) the test is very simple: check each edge of the polygon, assuming each edge is oriented in counterclockwise direction, and test whether the point lies *to the left* of the edge (in the left-hand half-plane). If all edges pass the test - the point is inside. If at least one fails - the point is outside.

In order to test whether the point `(xp, yp)` lies on the left-hand side of the edge `(x1, y1) - (x2, y2)`, you just need to calculate

```
D = (x2 - x1) * (yp - y1) - (xp - x1) * (y2 - y1)
```

If `D > 0`, the point is on the left-hand side. If `D < 0`, the point is on the right-hand side. If `D = 0`, the point is on the line.

---

The previous version of this answer described a seemingly different version of left-hand side test (see below). But it can be easily shown that it calculates the same value.

... In order to test whether the point `(xp, yp)` lies on the left-hand side of the edge `(x1, y1) - (x2, y2)`, you need to build the line equation for the line containing the edge. The equation is as follows

```
A * x + B * y + C = 0
```

where

```
A = -(y2 - y1)
B = x2 - x1
C = -(A * x1 + B * y1)
```

Now all you need to do is to calculate

```
D = A * xp + B * yp + C
```

If `D > 0`, the point is on the left-hand side. If `D < 0`, the point is on the right-hand side. If `D = 0`, the point is on the line.

However, this test, again, works for any convex polygon, meaning that it might be too generic for a rectangle. A rectangle might allow a simpler test... For example, in a rectangle (or in any other parallelogram) the values of `A` and `B` have the same magnitude but different signs for opposing (i.e. parallel) edges, which can be exploited to simplify the test.

Comment: That is true only for mathematician coordinates set. On the PC screen and  for GPS the directions of axis are different and you can't be sure you have the correct set of inequations. Or you can be sure you haven't. My answer is better :-).

Comment: AndreyT @Gangnus, quick precision, you only need to check that the sign of the equation is the same for all the points of the convex shape in relation to P, this allows you to not worry about coordinate systems or which direction your convex shape is defined ;))

Comment: There's a couple of extensions to this that let you speed things up. 1. Since the two opposite sides of the rectangle are parallel, their A,B coefficients can be the same. 2. Since the other two sides are perpendicular to these, their coefficients `A'` and `B'` can be given by `A'=B` and `B'=-A`. 3. There's no point calculating `A xp + B yp` for both edges so combine them into a single test. Then your test for being in a rectangle becomes `(v_min < A xp + B yp < v_max) && ( w_min < B xp - A yp < w_max )`.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson And what are `v_min`, etc?

Comment: `v_min` is the minimum value of `A x + B y` for all values in the interior of the rectangle (which is the minimum value when evaluated at the corners). `v_max` is the corresponding maximum. The `w_?` values are the same, but for `Bx - A y`.

Comment: I see... Are you saying that the value of `A x + B y` and `B x - A y` should be the *same* at each corner?

Answer (score 58):

Assuming the rectangle is represented by three points A,B,C, with AB and BC perpendicular, you only need to check the projections of the query point M on AB and BC:

```
0 <= dot(AB,AM) <= dot(AB,AB) &&
0 <= dot(BC,BM) <= dot(BC,BC)
```

`AB` is vector AB, with coordinates (Bx-Ax,By-Ay), and `dot(U,V)` is the dot product of vectors U and V: `Ux*Vx+Uy*Vy`.

**Update**. Let's take an example to illustrate this: A(5,0) B(0,2) C(1,5) and D(6,3).
From the point coordinates, we get AB=(-5,2), BC=(1,3), dot(AB,AB)=29, dot(BC,BC)=10.

For query point M(4,2), we have AM=(-1,2), BM=(4,0), dot(AB,AM)=9, dot(BC,BM)=4. M is inside the rectangle.

For query point P(6,1), we have AP=(1,1), BP=(6,-1), dot(AB,AP)=-3, dot(BC,BP)=3. P is not inside the rectangle, because its projection on side AB is not inside segment AB.

Comment: 0,2 - 10,2 - 10,10 - 2,10 is not a rectangle.

Comment: Please plot the points, and consider verifying the accuracy of your first comment.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: I like that this answer is concise, keeps the number of operations more or less as low as the other good answers here, but also has the advantage of being very intuitive and visualizable.

Comment: Here is a video I made to visualize this insight which helped me understand the terms. ​https://youtu.be/srqhPL4nWlI

Comment: Part 1: 0 <= ( AB • AM ) <= ( AB • AB)  This constraint is checking if the point M, projected onto the line formed by AB,  falls within the range of the line defined by A and B. In other words, when M is projected onto AB, this inequality tells us if M is between A and B. If A and B form one of a rectangle's side edges, then this is the same as checking if a point is above or below the rectangle. If this equality holds, then M is neither above nor below the rectangle meaning that it lies within range.

Comment: Part 2: However, ensuring that the points is neither above nor below a rectangle is not sufficient to tell if it is within the rectangle. We also need to check if M is too far to the left or right of the rectangle. This is achieved in the same way, we just need to use a new side of the rectangle. It needs to be an adjacent side because checking if M is between AB is the same as checking if M is between CD (because two opposite sides of a rectangle are equal in length and parallel). So we just repeat the process with BC instead of AB:
0 <= ( BC • BM ) <= ( BC • BC )

Answer (score 35):

I've borrowed from Eric Bainville's answer:

```js
0 <= dot(AB,AM) <= dot(AB,AB) && 0 <= dot(BC,BM) <= dot(BC,BC)
```

Which in javascript looks like this:

```js
function pointInRectangle(m, r) {
    var AB = vector(r.A, r.B);
    var AM = vector(r.A, m);
    var BC = vector(r.B, r.C);
    var BM = vector(r.B, m);
    var dotABAM = dot(AB, AM);
    var dotABAB = dot(AB, AB);
    var dotBCBM = dot(BC, BM);
    var dotBCBC = dot(BC, BC);
    return 0 <= dotABAM && dotABAM <= dotABAB && 0 <= dotBCBM && dotBCBM <= dotBCBC;
}

function vector(p1, p2) {
    return {
        x: (p2.x - p1.x),
        y: (p2.y - p1.y)
    };
}

function dot(u, v) {
    return u.x * v.x + u.y * v.y;
}
```

eg:

```js
var r = {
    A: {x: 50, y: 0},
    B: {x: 0, y: 20},
    C: {x: 10, y: 50},
    D: {x: 60, y: 30}
};

var m = {x: 40, y: 20};
```

then:

```js
pointInRectangle(m, r); // returns true.
```

Here's a codepen to draw the output as a visual test :)
http://codepen.io/mattburns/pen/jrrprN

[image]

Comment: Hi @matt burns I used your method and put it in a test project of mine: https://jsfiddle.net/caymanbruce/06wjp2sk/6/ But I couldn't make it work. No idea why it is still testing the point within the original rectangle with no rotation. I use a `mouseover` event in my project so whenever the mouse is over the point that is supposed to be inside the rectangle it will display a black circle dot around the mouse, and outside the rectangle it should display nothing. I need help to get it to work but I am so confused.

Comment: `mouseover` should be `mousemove`, just typo.

Comment: [Reference](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle/190373#190373)

Comment: In principle your method is correct, but your rectangle is not a rectangle in your example. I have made an improved version of yours over [here](https://codepen.io/JohannesB/pen/JjXqZJr) where I stick to the original formula and naming scheme, and where the input is in fact a true rectangle.

Answer (score 16):

```
# Pseudo code
# Corners in ax,ay,bx,by,dx,dy
# Point in x, y

bax = bx - ax
bay = by - ay
dax = dx - ax
day = dy - ay

if ((x - ax) * bax + (y - ay) * bay < 0.0) return false
if ((x - bx) * bax + (y - by) * bay > 0.0) return false
if ((x - ax) * dax + (y - ay) * day < 0.0) return false
if ((x - dx) * dax + (y - dy) * day > 0.0) return false

return true
```

Comment: Read this as: "if we connect the point to three vertexes of the rectangle then the angles between those segments and sides should be acute"

Comment: The problem with approaches like this is that they work in theory, but in paractice one might run into problems. The OP didn't say how the rectangle is represented. This answer assumes that it is represented by three points - `a`, `b` and `d`. While three points is a valid way to represent an arbitrary rectangle in theory, in practice it is impossible to do *precisely* in interger coordinates in general case. In general case one will end up with a parallelogram, which is very close to rectangle but still is not a rectangle.

Comment: I.e. the angles in that shape will not be exactly 90 deg. One has to be very careful when making any angle-based tests in such situation. Again, it depends on how the OP defines "inside" for an imprecisely represented "rectangle". And, again, on how the rectangle is represented.

Comment: +1 to both of your comments. Only @avd can tell us if this is good enough.

Comment: Works perfectly for me... Using trigonometry and geometry quite often, it's nice not having to come up with a formula to solve a common problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

I realise this is an old thread, but for anyone who's interested in looking at this from a purely mathematical perspective, there's an excellent thread on the maths stack exchange, here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle

Edit: Inspired by this thread, I've put together a simple vector method for quickly determining where your point lies.

Suppose you have a rectangle with points at `p1 = (x1, y1)`, `p2 = (x2, y2)`, `p3 = (x3, y3)` and `p4 = (x4, y4)`, going clockwise. If a point `p = (x, y)` lies inside the rectangle, then the dot product `(p - p1).(p2 - p1)` will lie between `0` and `|p2 - p1|^2`, and `(p - p1).(p4 - p1)` will lie between `0` and `|p4 - p1|^2`. This is equivalent to taking the projection of the vector `p - p1` along the length and width of the rectangle, with `p1` as the origin.

This may make more sense if I show an equivalent code:

```py
p21 = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
p41 = (x4 - x1, y4 - y1)

p21magnitude_squared = p21[0]^2 + p21[1]^2
p41magnitude_squared = p41[0]^2 + p41[1]^2

for x, y in list_of_points_to_test:

    p = (x - x1, y - y1)

    if 0 <= p[0] * p21[0] + p[1] * p21[1] <= p21magnitude_squared:
        if 0 <= p[0] * p41[0] + p[1] * p41[1]) <= p41magnitude_squared:
            return "Inside"
        else:
            return "Outside"
    else:
        return "Outside"
```

And that's it. It will also work for parallelograms.

Comment: Can you summarize the discussion there so far? Otherwise, this should probably have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 8):

```cpp
    bool pointInRectangle(Point A, Point B, Point C, Point D, Point m ) {
        Point AB = vect2d(A, B);  float C1 = -1 * (AB.y*A.x + AB.x*A.y); float  D1 = (AB.y*m.x + AB.x*m.y) + C1;
        Point AD = vect2d(A, D);  float C2 = -1 * (AD.y*A.x + AD.x*A.y); float D2 = (AD.y*m.x + AD.x*m.y) + C2;
        Point BC = vect2d(B, C);  float C3 = -1 * (BC.y*B.x + BC.x*B.y); float D3 = (BC.y*m.x + BC.x*m.y) + C3;
        Point CD = vect2d(C, D);  float C4 = -1 * (CD.y*C.x + CD.x*C.y); float D4 = (CD.y*m.x + CD.x*m.y) + C4;
        return     0 >= D1 && 0 >= D4 && 0 <= D2 && 0 >= D3;}

   

    

    Point vect2d(Point p1, Point p2) {
        Point temp;
        temp.x = (p2.x - p1.x);
        temp.y = -1 * (p2.y - p1.y);
        return temp;}
```

[image: Points inside polygon]

I just implemented AnT's Answer using c++. I used this code to check whether the pixel's coordination(X,Y)  lies inside the shape or not.

Comment: Some explanation for what you're doing here would be really helpful.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks. I converted what you had to work for a Unity Shader and reduced it for 3 points instead of 4. Worked well! Cheers.

Comment: It worked for me, here is an implementation in C# I made for Unity DOTS: https://gist.github.com/rgoupil/04b59be8ddb56c992f25e1489c61b310

Answer (score 6):

If you can't solve the problem for the rectangle try dividing the problem in to easier problems.
Divide the rectangle into 2 triangles an check if the point is inside any of them like they explain in [here](http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=6034)

*Essentially, you cycle through the edges on every two pairs of lines from a point. Then using cross product to check if the point is between the two lines using the cross product. If it's verified for all 3 points, then the point is inside the triangle. The good thing about this method is that it does not create any float-point errors which happens if you check for angles.*

Comment: That is correct, but terribly ineffective algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

## If a point is inside a rectangle. On a plane. For mathematician or geodesy (GPS) coordinates

- Let the rectangle be set by vertices A, B, C, D. The point is P. Coordinates are rectangular: x, y.
- Lets prolong the sides of the rectangle. So we have 4 straight lines l<sub>AB</sub>, l<sub>BC</sub>, l<sub>CD</sub>, l<sub>DA</sub>, or, for shortness, l<sub>1</sub>, l<sub>2</sub>, l<sub>3</sub>, l<sub>4</sub>.
- Make an equation for every l<sub>i</sub>. The equation sort of:

  f<sub>i</sub>(P)=0.

*P is a point. For points, belonging to l<sub>i</sub>, the equation is true.*

- We need the functions on the left sides of the equations. They are f<sub>1</sub>, f<sub>2</sub>, f<sub>3</sub>, f<sub>4</sub>.
- Notice, that for every point from one side of l<sub>i</sub> the function f<sub>i</sub> is greater than 0, for points from the other side f<sub>i</sub> is lesser than 0.
- So, if we are checking for P being in rectangle, we only need for the p to be on correct sides of all four lines. So, we have to check four functions for their signs.
- But what side of the line is the correct one, to which the rectangle belongs? It is the side, where lie the vertices of rectangle that don't belong to the line. For checking we can choose anyone of two not belonging vertices.
- So, we have to check this:

  f<sub>AB</sub>(P) f<sub>AB</sub>(C) >= 0

  f<sub>BC</sub>(P) f<sub>BC</sub>(D) >= 0

  f<sub>CD</sub>(P) f<sub>CD</sub>(A) >= 0

  f<sub>DA</sub>(P) f<sub>DA</sub>(B) >= 0

*The unequations are not strict, for if a point is on the border, it belongs to the rectangle, too. If you don't need points on the border, you can change inequations for strict ones. But while you work in floating point operations, the choice is irrelevant.*

- For a point, that is in the rectangle, all four inequations are true. Notice, that it works also for every convex polygon, only the number of lines/equations will differ.
- The only thing left is to get an equation for a line going through two points. It is a well-known linear equation. Let's write it for a line AB and point P:

  f<sub>AB</sub>(P)   ≡  
  (x<sub>A</sub>-x<sub>B</sub>) (y<sub>P</sub>-y<sub>B</sub>) - (y<sub>A</sub>-y<sub>B</sub>) (x<sub>P</sub>-x<sub>B</sub>)

The check could be simplified - let's go along the rectangle **clockwise** - A, B, C, D, A. Then all correct sides will be to the right of the lines. So, we needn't compare with the side where another vertice is. And we need check a set of shorter inequations:

f<sub>AB</sub>(P) >= 0

f<sub>BC</sub>(P) >= 0

f<sub>CD</sub>(P) >= 0

f<sub>DA</sub>(P) >= 0

But this is correct for the normal, **mathematician** (from the school mathematics) set of coordinates, where X is to the right and Y to the top. And for the **geodesy** coordinates, as are used in GPS, where X is to the top, and Y is to the right, we have to turn the inequations:

f<sub>AB</sub>(P) <= 0

f<sub>BC</sub>(P) <= 0

f<sub>CD</sub>(P) <= 0

f<sub>DA</sub>(P) <= 0

*If you are not sure with the directions of axes, be careful with this simplified check - check for one point with the known placement, if you have chosen the correct inequations.*

Comment: "where X is to the top, and Y is to the right, we have to turn the inequations:" That depends on how do you determine "clockwise". If you consider the coordinates to be the mathematical ones, clockwise will become counter-clockwise automatically, and you can still use the first very same set of inequalities. In other words, you may go well without this mess if you just consider the coordinates to be mathematical ones in all aspects. Reversing or exchanging the coordinates will have no effect on this predicate.

Comment: @Palo Mathematics has no orientation by itself. Yes. But the algorithm has several points and it would be much better to have understandable and sensible (in real life) results at any its point,for being able to test. Without that to the end of your second sentence you can hardly check if you are solving inequations correctly, using your space imagination.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I thought of was to just project the point onto the axis of the rectangle. Let me explain:

If you can get the vector from the center of the rectangle to the top or bottom edge and the left or right edge. And you also have a vector from the center of the rectangle to your point, you can project that point onto your width and height vectors.

P = point vector, H = height vector, W = width vector

Get Unit vector W', H' by dividing the vectors by their magnitude

proj_P,H = P - (P.H')H'
proj_P,W = P - (P.W')W'

Unless im mistaken, which I don't think I am... (Correct me if I'm wrong) but if the magnitude of the projection of your point on the height vector is less then the magnitude of the height vector (which is half of the height of the rectangle) and the magnitude of the projection of your point on the width vector is, then you have a point inside of your rectangle.

If you have a universal coordinate system, you might have to figure out the height/width/point vectors using vector subtraction. Vector projections are amazing! remember that.

Answer (score 0):

In continuation matts answer. we need to use 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle/190373#190373
solution to make it work

Below does not work
  0 <= dot(AB,AM) <= dot(AB,AB) && 0 <= dot(BC,BM) <= dot(BC,BC)

Below works
  0 <= dot(AB,AM) <= dot(AB,AB) && 0 <= dot(AM,AC) <= dot(AC,AC)

you check by pasting below in javascript console
            //Javascript solution for same

```
            var screenWidth = 320;
            var screenHeight = 568;
            var appHeaderWidth = 320;
            var AppHeaderHeight = 65;
            var regionWidth = 200;
            var regionHeight = 200;

            this.topLeftBoundary = {
                A: {x: 0, y: AppHeaderHeight},
                B: {x: regionWidth, y: AppHeaderHeight},
                C: {x: 0, y: regionHeight + AppHeaderHeight},
                D: {x: regionWidth, y: regionHeight + AppHeaderHeight}
            }

            this.topRightBoundary = {
                A: {x: screenWidth, y: AppHeaderHeight},
                B: {x: screenWidth - regionWidth, y: AppHeaderHeight},
                C: {x: screenWidth, y: regionHeight + AppHeaderHeight},
                D: {x: screenWidth - regionWidth, y: regionHeight + AppHeaderHeight}
            }

            this.bottomRightBoundary = {
                A: {x: screenWidth, y: screenHeight},
                B: {x: screenWidth - regionWidth, y: screenHeight},
                C: {x: screenWidth, y: screenHeight - regionHeight},
                D: {x: screenWidth - regionWidth, y: screenHeight - regionHeight}
            }

            this.bottomLeftBoundary = {
                A: {x: 0, y: screenHeight},
                B: {x: regionWidth, y: screenHeight},
                C: {x: 0, y: screenHeight - regionHeight},
                D: {x: regionWidth, y: screenHeight - regionHeight}
            }
            console.log(this.topLeftBoundary);
            console.log(this.topRightBoundary);
            console.log(this.bottomRightBoundary);
            console.log(this.bottomLeftBoundary);

            checkIfTapFallsInBoundary = function (region, point) {
                console.log("region " + JSON.stringify(region));
                console.log("point" + JSON.stringify(point));

                var r = region;
                var m = point;

                function vector(p1, p2) {
                    return {
                        x: (p2.x - p1.x),
                        y: (p2.y - p1.y)
                    };
                }

                function dot(u, v) {
                    console.log("DOT " + (u.x * v.x + u.y * v.y));
                    return u.x * v.x + u.y * v.y;
                }

                function pointInRectangle(m, r) {
                    var AB = vector(r.A, r.B);
                    var AM = vector(r.A, m);
                    var AC = vector(r.A, r.C);
                    var BC = vector(r.B, r.C);
                    var BM = vector(r.B, m);

                    console.log("AB " + JSON.stringify(AB));
                    console.log("AM " + JSON.stringify(AM));
                    console.log("AM " + JSON.stringify(AC));
                    console.log("BC " + JSON.stringify(BC));
                    console.log("BM " + JSON.stringify(BM));

                    var dotABAM = dot(AB, AM);
                    var dotABAB = dot(AB, AB);
                    var dotBCBM = dot(BC, BM);
                    var dotBCBC = dot(BC, BC);
                    var dotAMAC = dot(AM, AC);
                    var dotACAC = dot(AC, AC);

                    console.log("ABAM " + JSON.stringify(dotABAM));
                    console.log("ABAB " + JSON.stringify(dotABAB));
                    console.log("BCBM " + JSON.stringify(dotBCBM));
                    console.log("BCBC " + JSON.stringify(dotBCBC));
                    console.log("AMAC " + JSON.stringify(dotAMAC));
                    console.log("ACAC" + JSON.stringify(dotACAC));

                    var check = ((0 <= dotABAM && dotABAM <= dotABAB) && (0 <= dotBCBM && dotBCBM <= dotBCBC));
                    console.log(" first check" + check);
                    var check = ((0 <= dotABAM && dotABAM <= dotABAB) && (0 <= dotAMAC && dotAMAC <= dotACAC));
                    console.log("second check" + check);
                    return check;
                }

                return pointInRectangle(m, r);
            }

        //var point = {x: 136, y: 342};

            checkIfTapFallsInBoundary(topLeftBoundary, {x: 136, y: 342});
            checkIfTapFallsInBoundary(topRightBoundary, {x: 136, y: 274});
            checkIfTapFallsInBoundary(bottomRightBoundary, {x: 141, y: 475});
            checkIfTapFallsInBoundary(bottomRightBoundary, {x: 131, y: 272});
            checkIfTapFallsInBoundary(bottomLeftBoundary, {x: 131, y: 272});
```