# checking if a point is inside a specified Rectangle

Tags: java, geometry

ok, so i'm doing an assignment for a Java class and one part of the assignment is to find out if a point is within the dimensions of a rectangle. so I created this code:

```
public boolean contains(Point p) {
    return (this.getLocation().getX() < p.getX() && this.getLocation().getY() < p.getY() &&
            this.getLocation().getX() + this.getWidth() > p.getX()  &&
            this.getLocation().getY() + this.getHeight() > p.getY());
}
```

I created a `Point` class as well, which is why I asked for a `Point p` parameter. To test this `boolean` I created a simple `if` statement in my Main class:

```
//check if one rectangle's point is inside another
if (rectangle.contains(rectangle2.getLocation()))
    System.out.println("the point is in the rectangle");
```

The location of the point is (6,7). The point, width, and height of rectangle 1 is (4,5), 9, and 3, respectively. I know for a fact that this point is inside the first rectangle, but the `println` statement is not showing, meaning there must be a problem with the `boolean` i created but I don't see an error, maybe my head is cloudy but can someone point out to me what's wrong here?

P.S. this is all Console work, i'm not dealing with some GUI or graphics programming.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752725/finding-whether-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle-or-not

Comment: I don't think it is related. I think this is a debugging task for our good student.

Comment: Can you post your getLocation method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks ok to me. I would check that your test case actually has the numbers you think it does; I would also check that your accessors are all returning the right values (I can't tell you the number of times I've implemented getX() as {return this.y;}). Other than that it's anyone's guess.

Comment: thanks, there was a part in my code where I mixed up the width and height values of a point, instead of x for width, and y for height, i had y for width and x for height.

Comment: @mastrgamr that's the reason for following one of main rules - **you should name your fields and methods with name showing thier usage**, so, plz, try `int width` in place of `int x`

Answer (score 11):

AWT Rectangle already has `contains` method. ( [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) )

Task seems about if you understand how naming spaces conflict. For example, if you are lazy (it's one of most admired qualities of a programmer), then you can write:

```
public static class Rectangle {
    java.awt.Rectangle _r;

    public Rectangle(int x, int y) {
        this._r = new java.awt.Rectangle(x, y);
    }
    public boolean contains(Point p) {
        return this._r.contains(p);
    }
}
```

You generally do not want to reimplementing features nor extend classes.

Comment: May I know why you wouldn't want to extend classes?

Comment: This is not applicable in most cases because it does not support floating point values.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when dealing with computer graphics, the top left point is (0,0) and the bottom right corner is (width, height).

This means that you should reverse your conditions

Comment: no luck, maybe it's worth mentioning i'm not dealing with graphics, this is all console work.

Comment: Regardless of the orientation the conditions involved remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Though its a naive method, I tried the following concept:

If the `Point` (px,py) is inside the given rectangle, the sum of areas of triangles formed by joining 2 rectangle points and the given point (say in anti-clockwise or clockwise direction) would be equal to the sum of rectangle.

I have a picture for the same, but due to low reputation (as I am a newbie), cannot post it.

When I was formulating this into actual Java code, I had to handle a situation where 
the area value with decimal part having 15 9s was rounded to its nearest integer.

Refer this code:

```
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;

public class PointInsideRect
{
    private static double square(double n)
    {
        return n*n;
    }
    private static double areaOfTriangle(
                int xa, int ya,
                int xb, int yb,
                int px, int py )
    {
        double side1 = sqrt(square(ya-yb) + square(xa-xb));
        double side2 = sqrt(square(ya-py) + square(xa-px));
        double side3 = sqrt(square(yb-py) + square(xb-px));

        double semi_perimeter = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;

        return sqrt(semi_perimeter
                    * ( semi_perimeter - side1 )
                    * ( semi_perimeter - side2 )
                    * ( semi_perimeter - side3 ));
    }

    private static double areaOfRect(
                int x1, int y1,
                int x2, int y2,
                int x3, int y3,
                int x4, int y4 )
    {
        double side1 = sqrt(square(y1-y2) + square(x1-x2));
        double side2 = sqrt(square(y2-y3) + square(x2-x3));
        return side1 * side2;
    }

    public boolean check(
                int x1, int y1,
                int x2, int y2,
                int x3, int y3,
                int x4, int y4, 
                int pointX, int pointY)
    {
        double tri1Area = areaOfTriangle(x1,y1, x2,y2, pointX,pointY);
        double tri2Area = areaOfTriangle(x2,y2, x3,y3, pointX,pointY);
        double tri3Area = areaOfTriangle(x3,y3, x4,y4, pointX,pointY);
        double tri4Area = areaOfTriangle(x4,y4, x1,y1, pointX,pointY);

        double rectArea = areaOfRect(x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4);

        double triAreaSum = tri1Area + tri2Area + tri3Area+ tri4Area;


        if(triAreaSum % Math.pow(10, 14) >= 0.999999999999999)
        {
            triAreaSum = Math.ceil(triAreaSum);
            System.out.println(triangleAreaSum);
        }
        return triAreaSum == rectArea;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PointInsideRect inRect = new PointInsideRect();

        System.out.println(inRect.check(1,1, 1,3, 3,3, 3,1, 2,2));
    }
}
```