# How to write a contains method for custom Shape class

Tags: java, equals, contains, shapes

I am trying to write a contains method for a custom Shape class, but I would prefer, if possible, to simply write my own method without implementing the Shape class.

However, how do I go about writing such a method that would test whether or not specified X & Y coordinates are either within my shape or on the border?

[edit]

Here is an example class

```
abstract class BoundedShape extends Shape {
  protected Point upperLeft;
  protected int width, height;
  public BoundedShape(Color color, Point corner, int wide, int high) {
    strokeColor = color;
    upperLeft = corner;
    width = wide;
    height = high;
  }
  public void setShape(Point firstPt, Point currentPt) {
    if (firstPt.x <= currentPt.x)
      if (firstPt.y <= currentPt.y)
        upperLeft = firstPt;
      else
        upperLeft = new Point(firstPt.x, currentPt.y);
    else if (firstPt.y <= currentPt.y)
      upperLeft = new Point(currentPt.x, firstPt.y);
    else
      upperLeft = currentPt;

    width = Math.abs(currentPt.x - firstPt.x);
    height = Math.abs(currentPt.y - firstPt.y);
  }
}
```

another

```
public class Line extends Shape {
  protected Point firstPoint;
  protected Point secondPoint;

  public Line(Color color, Point p1, Point p2) {
    strokeColor = color;
    firstPoint = p1;
    secondPoint = p2;
  }
  public void setEndPoint(Point endPoint) {
    secondPoint = endPoint;
  }
  public void draw(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(strokeColor);
    g2d.drawLine(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y, secondPoint.x,
        secondPoint.y);
  }
```

another

```
public class Rect extends BoundedShape {
  public Rect(Color color, Point corner, int wide, int high) {
    super(color, corner, wide, high);
  }
  public void draw(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(strokeColor);
    g2d.drawRect(upperLeft.x, upperLeft.y, width, height);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of your `Shape` class?

Comment: The base abstract class is incredibly simple that just features an abstract draw() method. It is implemented by custom shapes that are passed either Points, height/width, or x/y

Comment: Can you post code of various shape classes which extend `Shape`? Have you implemented any such class?

Comment: You may declare contains method in `Shape` that will need to be overridden by all the classes.

Comment: Right, but I am not implementing the java Shape class... I am struggling to determine how to write my own contains method

Comment: Please use the idea I suggested. Also let me know if it helps in resolving your problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to declare `contains()` method in abstract class `Shape` as:

```
abstract public class Shape {
    abstract boolean contains(Point point);
    double distance(Point a, Point b) {
        return Math.sqrt((a.getX()-b.getX())*(a.getX()-b.getX()) + (a.getY()-b.getY())*(a.getY()-b.getY()));
    }
}
```

The method `distance()` will be used to compute the distance between two points. Now you need to implement `contains()` in Line as:

```
public class Line extends Shape {
    private Point firstPoint;
    private Point secondPoint;

    public Line(Point firstPoint, Point secondPoint) {
        this.firstPoint = firstPoint;
        this.secondPoint = secondPoint;
    }

    @Override
    boolean contains(Point point) {
       return (distance(firstPoint, point) + distance(secondPoint, point) == distance(firstPoint, secondPoint));
    }

}
```

And this can be tested as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape shape = new Line(new Point(10,10),new Point(10,40));
        boolean result = shape.contains(new Point(10,20));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

The output of the above code is `true`. Now you can write similar methods for other classes e.g. Rectangle you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345031/checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-specified-rectangle).

Comment: I appreciate the help. To clarify, I am trying to select the shapes by mousePressed events, however, when implementing this, I am getting no hit detection... any suggestions?

Comment: I suppose your `mousePressed` event will contain the coordinates of point where mouse clicked. You need to use that particular point and pass it to `contains()` method of respective shape to determine whether point is in that shape or not.

Comment: Pulling my hair out over here

Comment: Ha ha ha. Dont worry I will help you :)

Comment: So I implemented the above passing coordinates from a mouseevent getPoint(), but my hit detection came up empty. I believe it has to do with lines having no width... Additionally, if I am looking for points located within a rectangle, for example, how would such code differ?

Comment: Are you able to get correct Point values in `mouseevent getPoint()` if yes then the logic should have passed. I tested it with some dummy data and i worked. I believe you are stuck somewhere else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77371/discussion-between-motifesta-and-akhil-mittal).

Comment: isn't Shape an interface?