# How to check if point is inside the rectangle around a diagonal line?

Tags: java, gwt, vector, java-canvas

First of all: I know I can calc the distance from a `point` to a `line` to check if the point was on the line. This is what I do for detecting clicks (with an `offset`) on a line.

But before that, I want to apply a general check around the `diagonal line`.
The line itself with Start and End point defines a rectangular area:

```
Pstart(sx, sy), Pend(ex, ey).
```

I can use boundary check to determine if the `Point(px, py)` was inside that `rectangle`:

```
sx <= px && ex >= px && sy <= px && ey >= py
```

But this only applies if the line goes from top left to bottom right.
If it goes a different direction I have to modify the algorithm. How could I use my formula above regardless of the line direction?

How can I get the formula to respect the direction accordingly?

Comment: Check co-ordinate sizes and swap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compare for `Math.min(sx, ex) <= px <= Math.max(sx, ex)` and likewise for the `y` dimension.

Answer (score 0):

[Line2D.ptSegDist(x1, y1, x2, y2, xP, yP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#ptSegDist%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) returns 0.0 iff the point (xP, yP) is on the line segment from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2). [Line2D.ptLineDist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#ptLineDist%28double,%20double%29) does the same thing for the infinite line.

Comment: That's what I do for deeper analysis, but I want to include a precheck to not having to run the ptSegDist algorithm against all my lines, but only the lines that lie inside the defined rectangle of the line start and end points.

Comment: @membersound: i think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752725/finding-whether-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle-or-not) may help you for that :)