# PostgreSQL - Rotate geometric type giving unexpected results

Tags: postgresql, rotation, geometry

I'm using PostgresSQL 9.5 to generate a rectangle ([geometric type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-geometric.html) BOX).
That works fine

```
SELECT Box(Point(-50, -100), Point(50, 100)) ; -- this works
```

Then I try to rotate that box around the origin (its center point). The [rotation function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-geometry.html) is both

```
*   Scaling/rotation    box '((0,0),(1,1))' * point '(2.0,0)'
/   Scaling/rotation    box '((0,0),(2,2))' / point '(2.0,0)'
```

where the x-point is the scaling factor (2.0 in this example) and the y-point is the rotation radians (0 in this example).

To check that the rotation is correct, I calculate the height, width and area of the box for each angle.

```
 SELECT
       xx.deg, -- angle in degrees
       xx.geom, -- geometry of box
       Area(xx.geom), 
       Center(xx.geom),
       Height(xx.geom),
       Width(xx.geom)
FROM   
      (SELECT deg,
               Box(Point(-5, -10), Point(5, 10)) / Point(1, Radians(deg)) -- scale box by factor 1 and rotate by radians(degrees)
               AS geom
        FROM   Generate_series(0, 360, 90) AS deg  -- generate list of degrees from 0 to 360 by 90
) xx;
```

The results, which don't change between using `*` or `/` functions,

```
deg;geom;area;center;height;width
0;"(5,10),(-5,-10)";200;"(0,0)";20;10
90;"(5.97218570021291,0.618912639168559),(-5.97218570021291,-0.618912639168559)";14.785044853294;"(0,0)";1.23782527833712;11.9443714004258
180;"(3.35025316397424,0.525130727607429),(-3.35025316397424,-0.525130727607429)";7.03728352666753;"(0,0)";1.05026145521486;6.70050632794848
270;"(2.24607945852279,0.584400089411209),(-2.24607945852279,-0.584400089411209)";5.25043614554159;"(0,0)";1.16880017882242;4.49215891704558
360;"(1.67575357650576,0.529070250354662),(-1.67575357650576,-0.529070250354662)";3.5463654570185;"(0,0)";1.05814050070932;3.35150715301153
```

show that the box is being rotated but also scaled - the height, width and area are all not constant. I read somewhere that a rotation needs to take into account scaling, but I don't understand what scaling factor should be used to compsenate for the rotation. The documentation doesn't give any examples, and most of the resources online are for PostGIS (i.e. ST_Rotate).

---

**UPDATE**

I have a working solution that is not the fastest but gives correct results. See here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39680955/2327328

Comment: My similar question about rotating rectangles with Postgresql http://stackoverflow.com/q/39664127/2327328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL/DR: You cannot rotate boxes

The two operators `*` and `/` can be confusing. The idea is that they treat the two dimensional points as complex numbers and perform multiply (or divide) them as complex numbers. So for example `point '(2,3)' * point '(1,-1)'` returns `(5,1)` because `(2+3i)*(1-i)=5+i` or `point '(0,1)' * point '(0,1)'` returns `(-1,0)` because `i*i=-1`.

So if you want to use `*` to rotate by an angle say `φ`, you have to multiply by the complex number `exp(i*φ)` which is equal to `cos(φ)+i*sin(φ)`. For example:

```
SELECT point '(1,0)' * point(cos(radians(45)),sin(radians(45)));
=> (0.707106781186548,0.707106781186547)
```

rotates the point `(1,0)` by 45 degrees counter clockwise.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work very well with boxes. If you do

```
SELECT box '((0,0),(1,1))' * point(cos(radians(45)),sin(radians(45)));
=> (1.11022302462516e-16,1.41421356237309),(0,0)
```

which means that postgres rotated the two points as individual points and not the whole box. The problem is that a box is a rectangle with sides parallel to the x and y axes. By that definition, if you rotate a box by 45 degrees, what you get is not a box. So you cannot rotate boxes.

In theory, it should be possible to rotate polygons. Unfortunatelly, it seems that this has not been implemented (yet?) in postgresql:

```
$ SELECT polygon(box '((0,0),(1,1))') * point(1,0);
ERROR:  operator does not exist: polygon * point
LINE 1: SELECT polygon(box '((0,0),(1,1))') * point(1,0);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting there by rotating individual points, but not working 100% yet.

Comment: @philshem Remember, as I explain above, if you rotate a box, it will not be  a box anymore. So the solution has to involve polygons. I think it might be possible to define a custom function that rotates a polygon (since postgres doesn't provide one), but we need to find a way to extract its points as say an array of points.

Comment: I figured it out without using geometric types. I generate the vertices of the rectangle and then rotate each point http://stackoverflow.com/a/39680955/2327328

Comment: @philshem Good idea.