# Check if a point is within a cuboid

Tags: python, collision, detection

is there any python-lib which provides an algorithm (some sort of collision-detection algorithm?) to check if a Point in 3D is within a cuboid?

regards.

Comment: It depends on how you made your cuboid. If it is a solid body using something like `ACIS` they have functions that determine if a point is in a body. If you defined the corner points yourself, you can do the geometry relatively trivially.

Comment: thx for the advice. In my case, i dont know the Corners of the box. I just know the "base"-plane and the thickness, i.e. the box is infinitely Extended in two directions...

Comment: In that case, you can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752725/finding-whether-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle-or-not to check if it lies within the base plane. Then check if its z-value is between the bottom and bottom+thickness