# If position is between two points on a line with variable width

Tags: c#, math, 2d, coordinates

I have a coordinate grid in a 2D game.
I need to, on a line with variable width, find multiple targets for a projectile of a particular size.

The coordinates are absolute integer values.

In my grid, and for my situation, it's different from a typical X and Y axis.
For north, it's X-1, Y-1. South, X+1, Y+1. A diamond pattern.

```
                   0,0
               0,1 1,1 1,0
           0,2 1,2 2,2 2,1 2,0
       0,3 1,3 2,3 3,3 3,2 3,1 3,0
                  etc...
```

There are no negative coordinates.

[**Here is a visual example of what I hope to accomplish.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkSn3.png)
The two black lines represent an individual target area of individual collections, each of the red dots represent an object which needs to be verified as an object within a black line.

This is the original functional code that I want to adapt or replace.
The collection of coordinates it makes, in a line, is of a fixed width. I need something that can make a wider line of targeted coordinates when needed.

```
    List<coords> line(int xa, int ya, int xb, int yb)
    {
        int dx = xb - xa, dy = yb - ya, steps, k;
        float xincrement, yincrement, x = xa, y = ya;

        if (Math.Abs(dx) > Math.Abs(dy)) steps = Math.Abs(dx);
        else steps = Math.Abs(dy);

        xincrement = dx / (float)steps;
        yincrement = dy / (float)steps;
        var thisLine = new List<coords> {new coords(Math.Round(x), Math.Round(y))};

        for (k = 0; k < MaxDistance; k++)
        {
            x += xincrement;
            y += yincrement;
            thisLine.Add(new coords(Math.Round(x), Math.Round(y)));
        }
        return thisLine;
    }
```

Any answer should keep in mind that the collection is time sensitive and that performance is important since this will be used in a server environment.

Comment: So, you want points intersecting a (rotated) rectangle? But in a strange co-ordinate system..

Comment: OK, so your coordinate system is just rectangular, but you render it rotated by 45 degrees? So you could use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752725/finding-whether-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle-or-not)?

Comment: Not really. Basically I need a DDA line algorithm that can draw a line with extra thickness. Bresenham, but modified to have thickened lines.. and perhaps variation.

Comment: is there a difference between a thick line and a rectangle? it sounds like you want to draw a rectangle around a given set of selected coordinates (rather than determine if a coordinate is inside a rectangle)?

Comment: This won't be used for graphics. Just a trajectory across the above depicted grid. Also I think drawing a rectangle would be too complicated for something which needs to be a quick execution.