# Determine if a geoPoint fits inside a rectangle

Tags: latitude-longitude, geopoints

How can I determine if a latitude/longitude fits in a rectangle? 
This rectangle is built by two `GeoPoints` (minLat/minLong, maxLat/maxLong).

We could resolve without Solr or ElasticSearch?

Comment: Sounds like simple geometry.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: These questions have answers that will likely be useful: [How to check if a point is inside a rectangle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle) and [Finding whether a point lies inside a rectangle or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752725/finding-whether-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle-or-not)

Comment: Is MySQL involved?  If so, do you have a Spatial index?  If not, remove it from the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description of how the rectangle is built, it sounds as if you just need to check that your latitude and longitude are within the min/max values