# How to detect if mouse is moving in clockwise direction

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation, html5-canvas

I want to rotate a shape on canvas on mouse move, and I want to detect if mouse is moving in `clockwise direction` or not, but I do not know how to do that. Here is my code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var img = document.getElementById('photo');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var annotation_rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
rect = {
      startX : 150,
      startY : 50,
      w : 250,
      h : 150,
      endX : 0,
      endY : 0,
      rotate: 0
    };
var drag = false;
var rotating = false;
var update = true; // when true updates canvas
var rotate_angle = 5; // in degrees - for rotating blurred part
var angle = rotate_angle * (Math.PI / 180);
var original_source = img.src;
img.src = original_source;

function rotateRight(){
 rect.rotate += angle;
  update = true;
}

function rotateLeft(){
 rect.rotate -= angle;
  update = true;
}

function init() {
    img.addEventListener('load', function(){
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
    });
    
    // start the rendering loop
    requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}

// main render loop only updates if update is true
function updateCanvas(){
  if(update){
      drawCanvas();
      update = false;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}

// draws a rectangle with rotation 
function drawRect(){
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,rect.startX + rect.w / 2, rect.startY + rect.h / 2);
    ctx.rotate(rect.rotate);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
    ctx.filter = 'blur(10px)';
    ctx.rect(-rect.w/2, -rect.h/2, rect.w, rect.h);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

// clears canvas sets filters and draws rectangles
function drawCanvas(){    
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawRect()
}

// create new rect add to array 
function mouseDown(e) {
    drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() { drag = false; update = true; }



function startRotation(e){
    rotating = true;
}

function stopRotation(e){
    rotating = false;
}

function onShapeRotating(e){
    if(rotating){
         rotateRight();
    }
} 



function mouseMove(e) {
  var mouseX = e.offsetX - annotation_rect.left,
      mouseY = e.offsetY - annotation_rect.top,
        endX = rect.startX + rect.w,
      endY = rect.startY + rect.h
    
  var cursorOnShape = mouseX >= rect.startX && mouseX <= endX && mouseY >= rect.startY && mouseY <= endY;
    
    
    if(cursorOnShape){
        canvas.style.cursor = "pointer"
        
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startRotation, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopRotation, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onShapeRotating, false);
    }else{    
        canvas.style.cursor = "default"
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', startRotation, false);
        canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopRotation, false);
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onShapeRotating, false);
    }
}

init();
```

```css
canvas{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  display:inline-block;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;display:inline-block;">
    <img id="photo" src="https://carsales.pxcrush.net/carsales/car/cil/cc5166737225893351785.jpg?width=600&height=300&overlay&aspect=FitWithIn&watermark=1439104668"/>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Thus I have an rect drawn on canvas and I detect if the mouse is on that rect and if it is I call the function `rotateShape` and there I call the function `rotateRight`. And that is working. If you are on the rect with mouse and you press it down and rotate it would rotate the rect calling the function `rotateRight`.

But I want to be able to check if the mouse is **moving in clockwise direction or not**. If it moves in clockwise direction I would call `rotateRight` and if not then I would call `rotateLeft`.

Any idea how to do that?

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/cyrjawv7/203/)

Comment: var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y); use this center of your object, by that I meant.

Comment: @nullqube Can you apply it in the fiddle?

Comment: your code needs much more change than just that, first you don't send the mouse position to the startRotation and then generally a bit of unnecessary complexity, and your fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: @nullqube It's not true. The fiddle works fine. An I have much more code but I tried to make it simpler for fiddle. Obviously you didn't understood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rotating by a fixed value, rotate by the difference between the last known angle and the new one.

To get these angles, you can use

```
var angle = Math.atan2(
  e.clientY - (rect.startY + rect.h /2),
  e.clientX - (rect.startX + rect.w /2)
);
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var img = document.getElementById('photo');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var annotation_rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
rect = {
  startX: 150,
  startY: 50,
  w: 250,
  h: 150,
  endX: 0,
  endY: 0,
  rotate: 0
};
var drag = false;
var rotating = false;
var update = true; // when true updates canvas
var original_source = img.src;
img.src = original_source;

// keep track of the last angle
var prevAngle = null;
// a single function
function rotate(angle) {
  rect.rotate += angle;
  update = true;
}
// called on mousemove when dragging
function onShapeRotating(e) {
  if (rotating) {
    var angle = Math.atan2(
      e.clientY - (rect.startY + rect.h / 2),
      e.clientX - (rect.startX + rect.w / 2)
    );
    if (prevAngle !== null)
      rotate(angle - prevAngle)
    prevAngle = angle;
  }
}

function init() {
  img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
  });

  // start the rendering loop
  requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}

// main render loop only updates if update is true
function updateCanvas() {
  if (update) {
    drawCanvas();
    update = false;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}

// draws a rectangle with rotation 
function drawRect() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, rect.startX + rect.w / 2, rect.startY + rect.h / 2);
  ctx.rotate(rect.rotate);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
  ctx.filter = 'blur(10px)';
  ctx.rect(-rect.w / 2, -rect.h / 2, rect.w, rect.h);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

// clears canvas sets filters and draws rectangles
function drawCanvas() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawRect()
}

// create new rect add to array 
function mouseDown(e) {
  drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() {
  prevAngle = null;
  drag = false;
  update = true;
}



function startRotation(e) {
  rotating = true;
}

function stopRotation(e) {
  rotating = false;
}


function mouseMove(e) {
  var mouseX = e.offsetX - annotation_rect.left,
    mouseY = e.offsetY - annotation_rect.top,
    endX = rect.startX + rect.w,
    endY = rect.startY + rect.h

  var cursorOnShape = mouseX >= rect.startX && mouseX <= endX && mouseY >= rect.startY && mouseY <= endY;


  if (cursorOnShape) {
    canvas.style.cursor = "pointer"

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startRotation, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopRotation, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onShapeRotating, false);
  } else {
    canvas.style.cursor = "default"
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', startRotation, false);
    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopRotation, false);
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onShapeRotating, false);
  }
}

init();
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;display:inline-block;">
  <img id="photo" src="https://carsales.pxcrush.net/carsales/car/cil/cc5166737225893351785.jpg?width=600&height=300&overlay&aspect=FitWithIn&watermark=1439104668" />
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

---

Now, your code has a lot of things to be fixed, but I'll let it to you.

You'd be better have single events on the whole canvas/document rather than adding ones selectively.
Your `cursorOnShape` algo doesn't take into account the rotation of your rectangle.

Comment: Thanks. So many times that you helped me. :) Many thanks. And any idea how to solve the problem with `cursorOnShape `?

Comment: @Boky randomly picked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268779/how-to-test-if-a-point-is-in-a-rectangle-area-which-rotates-an-angle

Answer (score 1):

## Computing change in angle

The problem with using `Math.atan2()` is that the difference between `Math.atan2(1,-10)` and `Math.atan2(-1,-10)` is 6.084 not 0.199 which means as you accumulate the sum of the differences you never get a value over `Math.PI` or under `-Math.PI`

In other words you can not directly track the number of turns you have made nor is it simple to know if you have turned clockwise or counter clockwise.

## Cross product

The best way to compute the direction and amount the mouse has rotated around a point is to use the cross product of the two vectors from the center to the mouse position and old position

```
// cx,cy center of rotation
// ox,oy old position of mouse
// mx,my new position of mouse.
function getAngle(cx, cy, ox, oy, mx, my){
    var x1 = ox - cx;
    var y1 = oy - cy;
    var x2 = mx - cx;
    var y2 = my - cy;
    var d1 = Math.sqrt(x1 * x1 + y1 * y1);
    var d2 = Math.sqrt(x2 * x2 + y2 * y2);

    return Math.asin((x1 / d1) * (y2 / d2) - (y1 / d1) * (x2 / d2));
}
```

The function will return a negative change in angle if counter clockwise and positive if clockwise.

### Example

Example show the above function being used to track the total rotation, not the absolute orientation as the other answers do.

```js
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, ox : 0, oy : 0, down : false};
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name,mouseEvents));
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function mouseEvents(e) {
  mouse.x = e.pageX; mouse.y = e.pageY;
  mouse.down = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.down;
}

function getAngleBetween(cx, cy, ox, oy, mx, my) {
  var x1 = ox - cx;
  var y1 = oy - cy;
  var x2 = mx - cx;
  var y2 = my - cy;
  // max to prevent div by zero
  var d1 = Math.max(0.001, Math.sqrt(x1 * x1 + y1 * y1));
  var d2 = Math.max(0.001, Math.sqrt(x2 * x2 + y2 * y2));
  return Math.asin((x1 / d1) * (y2 / d2) - (y1 / d1) * (x2 / d2));
}
var w, h, cw, ch;
var angle = 0;
function update() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
  if (w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight) {
    cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
    ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
  } else {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  }
  var change = 0;
  if (mouse.down) {
    change = getAngleBetween(cw, ch, mouse.ox, mouse.oy, mouse.x, mouse.y);
    angle += change;
  }

  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, cw, ch);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.fillRect(-100, -25, 200, 50);


  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.font = "28px arial";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillText("Total rotation : " + ((angle * 180 / Math.PI) | 0), cw, 30);
  ctx.font = "14px arial";
  ctx.fillText("Change : " + (change * 180 / Math.PI).toFixed(2), cw, 48);

  ctx.fillText("Click drag to rotate box.", cw, h - 20);

  mouse.ox = mouse.x;
  mouse.oy = mouse.y
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok here it is but not the appropriate way , sorry :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var img = document.getElementById('photo');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var annotation_rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
rect = {
      startX : 150,
      startY : 50,
      w : 250,
      h : 150,
      endX : 0,
      endY : 0,
      rotate: 0
    };
var drag = false;
var rotating = false;
var update = true; // when true updates canvas
var rotate_angle = 5; // in degrees - for rotating blurred part
var angle = rotate_angle * (Math.PI / 180);
var original_source = img.src;
var bLeft = true;
img.src = original_source;

function rotateRight(){
 rect.rotate += angle;
  update = true;
}

function rotateLeft(){
 rect.rotate -= angle;
  update = true;
}

function init() {
    img.addEventListener('load', function(){
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
    });
    
    // start the rendering loop
    requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}

// main render loop only updates if update is true
function updateCanvas(){
  if(update){
      drawCanvas();
      update = false;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}

// draws a rectangle with rotation 
function drawRect(){
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,rect.startX + rect.w / 2, rect.startY + rect.h / 2);
    ctx.rotate(rect.rotate);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
    ctx.filter = 'blur(10px)';
    ctx.rect(-rect.w/2, -rect.h/2, rect.w, rect.h);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

// clears canvas sets filters and draws rectangles
function drawCanvas(){    
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawRect()
}

// create new rect add to array 
function mouseDown(e) {
    drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() { drag = false; update = true; }



function startRotation(e){
    rotating = true;
}

function stopRotation(e){
    rotating = false;
}

function onShapeRotating(e){
    if(rotating && !bLeft){
         rotateRight();
    } else if(rotating && bLeft){
         rotateLeft();
    }
} 



function mouseMove(e) {
  var mouseX = e.offsetX - annotation_rect.left,
      mouseY = e.offsetY - annotation_rect.top,
        endX = rect.startX + rect.w,
      endY = rect.startY + rect.h
    
  var cursorOnShape = mouseX >= rect.startX && mouseX <= endX && mouseY >= rect.startY && mouseY <= endY;
    
    bLeft = ( rect.startX + rect.w/2 - mouseX ) > 0 ? true:false;
    if(cursorOnShape){
        canvas.style.cursor = "pointer"
        
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startRotation, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopRotation, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onShapeRotating, false);
    }else{    
        canvas.style.cursor = "default"
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', startRotation, false);
        canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopRotation, false);
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onShapeRotating, false);
    }
}

init();
```

```css
canvas{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  display:inline-block;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;display:inline-block;">
    <img id="photo" src="https://carsales.pxcrush.net/carsales/car/cil/cc5166737225893351785.jpg?width=600&height=300&overlay&aspect=FitWithIn&watermark=1439104668"/>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: since you did the state machine code, so I just added a bLeft variable that keeps track of direction. but the whole point is calc the diff between mouse pos and center of the shape you try to rotate.